# Obtener el dominio que invoca a un archivo remoto

Tags: php, url, curl, dominio

Tengo un archivo en php:
www.remoto.com/archivo.php

Y otro en un dominio diferente:
www.invocador.com/invocador.php

El archivo invocador le hace un file_get_contets() a archivo.php

Lo único que necesito es que archivo.php detecte desde qué dominio se lo esta invocando, para mostrar la info o no.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentarlo con **HTTP_HOST** o **SERVER_NAME**.

**Ejemplo:**

```
$domain = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

o tambien:

```
$domain = parse_url($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

[Mas informacion...](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php)